# Use data.table set() to convert all columns from integer to numeric

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a data.table that has 1900 columns and roughly 280,000 rows.

Currently, the data is entirely "integer", but I want them to explicitly "numeric" so I can pass it to a bigcor() function later. Apparently, bigcor() can only handle "numeric" and not "integer".

I have tried:

```
full.bind <- full.bind[,sapply(full.bind, as.numeric), with=FALSE]
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(full.bind, , sapply(full.bind, as.numeric), with = FALSE) : 
  j out of bounds
```

So, I tried using the data.table set() function, but I get the error:

```
Error in set(full.bind, value = as.numeric(full.bind)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I have created a simple reproducible example. Keep in mind, the actual columns are NOT "a", "b", or "c"; they are extremely complicated column names so referencing column individually is not a possibility.

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10)
```

So, my final questions are:

1) Why does my sapply technique not work? (what is the "j out of bounds" error?)
2) Why does the set() technique not? (why can't the data.table be coerced to numeric?)
3) Does the bigcor() function require a numeric object, or is there another problem?

Comment: One does not delete a question after receiving an answer. You got help for free so try to be grateful instead.

Comment: I actually tried to delete this immediately upon posting as I had found the answer somewhere else. Sorry about that!

Comment: not sure about differences between `data.frame` and `data.table` (so maybe this is irrelevant, sorry!), but I found `dplyr` to be helpful here: `mutate_if(df, is.integer, as.numeric)` converted all integer columns to numeric: clean, concise, quick.

Answer (score 22):

Use `.SD` and assignment by reference:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10)
sapply(dt, class)
#        a         b         c 
#"integer" "integer" "integer"

dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
sapply(dt, class)
#        a         b         c 
#"numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

`set` only works for one column here (note the documentation, which doesn't say that `j` is optional), because each replacement column has to be generated. You would need to loop over the columns (e.g., using a `for` loop) if you want to use it. It might be preferable because it needs less memory (additional memory need corresponds to one column whereas additional memory for the whole data.table is needed with the first approach).

```
for (k in seq_along(dt)) set(dt, j = k, value = as.character(dt[[k]]))
sapply(dt, class)
#         a           b           c 
#"character" "character" "character"
```

However, `bigcor` (from package propagate)  requires a matrix as input and a `data.table` isn't a matrix. So, your problem is not the column type, but you need to use `as.matrix(dt)`.

Comment: `set()` can work with more than one column simultaneously, but `value` has to be generated anyways for each column.. but prefer your `set()` approach because it requires memory worth one extra double column.. The `:=` with `lapply()` would have to convert every column to numeric first before to replace (which requires the size of entire data in double).

Comment: @Arun Thanks. I tried to add this to the answer. However, I prefer the first approach for its nicer syntax. I rarely am in a situation where I wouldn't have enough memory available for it.

Comment: How do you do it if you only want to change some columns? 
For example I want to exclude the 3rd:
dt[, names(.SD) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=!c(3)]
I get this error: Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(names(.SD), lapply(.SD, as.integer)),  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
And dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=!c(3)] gives another error:
In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(names(dt), lapply(.SD, as.integer)),  :
  Supplied 3 columns to be assigned a list (length 2) of values (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).

Comment: dt[, names(dt[-3]) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=!c(3)]   seems too long.